# AWS Api Gateway Generated Android SDK Crash on Response Code other than 200

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I tried to implement a generated android SDK from AWS api gateway following this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-android.html), but my app got crashed every time the response from api gateway is other than 200 or the request param is incorrect/null.

Here is the API client object initialisation :

```
@Provides
@ApplicationScope
public BigCRMClient bigCRMClient() {
    ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientConfiguration.setCurlLogging(true);
    ApiClientFactory apiClientFactory = new ApiClientFactory();
    apiClientFactory.clientConfiguration(clientConfiguration);
    return apiClientFactory.build(BigCRMClient.class);
}
```

API invocation :

```
Completable.create(e -> {
        bigCRMClient.contactsPost(BuildConfig.BIG_CRM_TOKEN, bigCRMContact);
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe();
```

I tried to change the thread invocation but still crashed.
And the crash log :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.erasys.siaga, PID: 10492
Theme: themes:{default=overlay:system, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:system, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientException: {
"body-json" : {"error":["duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"contacts_email_brand_id_7d9a6f1a_uniq\"\nDETAIL:  Key (email, brand_id)=(adityahas@gmail.com, 19) already exists.\n"]},
"params" : {
"path" : {
    }
    ,"querystring" : {
    }
    ,"header" : {
        "Accept" : "application\/json"
        ,        "Accept-Encoding" : "identity"
        ,        "Authorization" : "token b73a34e395389bc46e269ba0d52c256079c00f50"
        ,        "Content-Type" : "application\/json"
        ,        "Host" : "w2lyh239oi.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com"
        ,        "User-Agent" : "aws-sdk-android\/2.7.6 Linux\/3.10.49-Lineage\uFFE2\uFF84\uFFA2+ Dalvik\/2.1.0\/0 en_US BigCRMClient"
        ,        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id" : "Root=1-5bd915de-c6a38cd8a328223013769f40"
        ,        "X-Forwarded-For" : "36.73.117.238"
        ,        "X-Forwarded-Port" : "443"
        ,        "X-Forwarded-Proto" : "https"
            }
    },
"stage-variables" : {
},
"context" : {
    "account-id" : "",
    "api-id" : "w2lyh239oi",
    "api-key" : "",
    "authorizer-principal-id" : "",
    "caller" : "",
    "cognito-authentication-provider" : "",
    "cognito-authentication-type" : "",
    "cognito-identity-id" : "",
    "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "",
    "http-method" : "POST",
    "stage" : "Beta",
    "source-ip" : "36.73.117.238",
    "user" : "",
    "user-agent" : "aws-sdk-android/2.7.6 Linux/3.10.49-Lineage\uFFE2\uFF84\uFFA2+ Dalvik/2.1.0/0 en_US BigCRMClient",
    "user-arn" : "",
    "request-id" : "2ef1630f-dcb6-11e8-a9e4-45da7d034736",
    "resource-id" : "74fckx",
    "resource-path" : "/contacts"
    }
}
 (Service: BigCRMClient; Status Code: 400; Error Code: null; Request ID: 2ef1630f-dcb6-11e8-a9e4-45da7d034736)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.handleResponse(ApiClientHandler.java:294)
    at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.invoke(ApiClientHandler.java:111)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
    at $Proxy4.contactsPost(Unknown Source)
    at com.erasys.siaga.activity.login.LoginPresenter.lambda$registerCRMUser$5$LoginPresenter(LoginPresenter.java:271)
    at com.erasys.siaga.activity.login.LoginPresenter$$Lambda$6.subscribe(Unknown Source)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableCreate.subscribeActual(CompletableCreate.java:39)
    at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:1517)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableObserveOn.subscribeActual(CompletableObserveOn.java:34)
    at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:1517)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(CompletableSubscribeOn.java:64)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:134)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:59)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:51)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```